# Converting character data to date --COVID 19 research

Tags: r, date

Need help converting character data into date:

The time/date looks like this: `4/10/20 17:36`

I need to convert the column from character into date in order to sort the column by the date. My data frame is `o2outcomes` and my column is `transfusion_date`

I've tried:

1. `o2outcomes$transfusion_date <- as.Date(c("2007-06-22", "2004-02-13"))`
2. `o2outcomes$transfusion_date <- as.Date(o2outcomes$transfusion_date , "%m/%d/%Y %H%M")`
3. `o2outcomes <- data.frame(Date = c("10/9/2009 0:00:00", "10/15/2009 0:00:00"))
   as.Date(o2outcomes$transfusion_date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`

For arranging the data by date I've tried:

1. `o2outcomes$V8 <- lubridate::dmy(o2outcomes$transfusion_date)
   dplyr::arrange(o2outcomes$transfusion_date)`
2. `o2outcomes[order(as.Date(o2outcomes$transfusion_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]`
3. `test <- "2013-12-25T04:32:16.500-08:00`

`z <- as.POSIXct(test,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
z`

`'test <- "2013-12-25 04:32:16.5 CST"
as.POSIXct(test)`

4.
    `o2outcomes$V8 <- lubridate::dmy(o2outcomes$transfusion_date)
dplyr::arrange(o2outcomes$transfusion_date)`

5.
`o2outcomes[order(as.Date(o2outcomes$transfusion_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]`

This is a time sensitive COVID study (the first in the nation for plasma therapy!) and I've been tasked with creating these figures despite never having used R before. So thanks in advance.

Kate

Comment: `lubridate::ymd`? Do you have mixed formats?

Answer (score 4):

Let s make up some data. You dont need to do this, since you have your data already. I suppose you possibly have more columns, that is not a problem.

```
o2outcomes <- data.frame(transfusion_date= c("4/10/20 17:36", "4/10/20 17:33", "4/11/20 17:36"),
                     other = letters[1:3])
```

This is how it looks like:

```
  transfusion_date other
1    4/10/20 17:36     a
2    4/10/20 17:33     b
3    4/11/20 17:36     c
```

Now parse the dates and then order the dataset by time:

```
library(lubridate)

# parse date
o2outcomes$transfusion_date <- parse_date_time(o2outcomes$transfusion_date,
                                               orders = "%m/%d/%y %H%M")

# sort
o2outcomes <- o2outcomes[order(o2outcomes$transfusion_date),]

o2outcomes
     transfusion_date other
2 2020-04-10 17:33:00     b
1 2020-04-10 17:36:00     a
3 2020-04-11 17:36:00     c
```

Comment: Apologies in advance for the basic question. When I run this, it takes my dataset down to just these values "4/10/20 17:36", "4/10/20 17:33", "4/11/20 17:36" instead of the 73 rows I originally had. Am I supposed to be entering in all 73 of the date/times into quotations?

Comment: At the end of running the code my data was called "op", the original data was gone, and there was a list of 1.  Also, just want to confirm (so basic!), this part: " o2outcomes
     transfusion_date
1 2020-04-10 17:33:00..." is just an example of the output and not part of the code.

Comment: @Kate You dont need to use my data, I made up some just to show how the code works. Just apply the code to your data. Also, if your data is indeed called  o2outcomes you could paste the output of `dput(o2outcomes[1:10,])` into your question, so we see how it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

@desval's answer is fine. The date-time conversion part can also be done with `strptime()` from base R:

```
o2outcomes <- transform(o2outcomes,
          td = strptime(transfusion_date, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
          )
```

Or, if you convert the two-digit year to a four-digit year, the `anytime` package can handle it:

```
o2outcomes <- transform(o2outcomes,
          td = anytime::anytime(gsub("/20 ","/2020 ",transfusion_date))
          )
```

(in this case I was using a new variable name rather than replacing the original, but you can do whatever works best).

Comment: yes, `lubridate` makes things so much easier (in general) when working with dates and time that I forgot about the base R way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

o2outcomes <- transform(o2outcomes,
                        td = anytime::anytime(gsub("/20 ","/2020 ",transfusion_date))
)

### convert data from character into date

o2outcomes <- o2outcomes[order(o2outcomes$transfusion_date),]

### sort data by date

A combo of the two answers above worked. Thank you guys

Comment: sure? It seems to me that you are ordering using the non-formatted date

Comment: you are correct. I needed to include your line       # parse date
o2outcomes$transfusion_date <- parse_date_time(o2outcomes$transfusion_date,
                                               orders = "%m/%d/%y %H%M")